# AJAX form submit only works on first submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

SCRIPT.JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'data/addtext.php',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#meo').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

INDEX.PHP

```
<div id="meo"></div>
```

ADDTEXT.PHP

```
<?php echo "HELLO WORLD" ?>
```

So above is my codes. What I want to happen is every time I submit the form, the word "HELLO WORLD" will be printed out, this code is working on the first click submit the output will be

```
HELLO WORLD
```

Now, I want to print it out again so I will click the submit button again, but at the second submit, nothing is printing out. why?

The output I want is

```
HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD
```

In other words, I want to print out the "HELLO WORLD" on every submit but the old output will be remain. So If I submit the form  3 times then the output should be

```
HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD HELLO WORLD
```

I know I can do this using append and without using form, But I want to do it using form ajax without page reloading.  Again this code is working but only on the first click submit.

Why is it not working on the second click submit?

Comment: You are not appending the result to `#meo` you are completely replacing it each time.  Instead of `$('#meo').html(result);` try `$('#meo').html($('#meo').text() + result);`

Comment: @ochi , I finally got it because of your comment, the answer is so simple and I didnt noticed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not appending the result to `#meo` you are completely replacing it each time.

Instead of

`$('#meo').html(result);`

Try appending `result` to the existing values/html in `#meo`. Like:

`$('#meo').html($('#meo').text() + result);`

Comment: Its working, thanks! I didn't realize that I am replacing it each time I submit it.

Answer (score 2):

`. html()` overrides content inside the element that you set. try `. append()` instead.

Comment: This is also working. Thanks. Gonna upvote this once I reach 15 reputation.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'data/addtext.php',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (result) {
                // This should work for you
                $('#meo').html($('#meo').html() + result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```